# understanding toolz use cases

Tags: python, functional-programming, toolz

I am learning a little functional programming and looking at toolz. The differences between compose, pipe, thread_first, and thread_last seem very subtle or non-existent to me. What is the intended different use cases for these functions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `compose` vs. `thread_*` and `pipe`

  `compose` is a essentially a [function compostion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) (∘). It's main goal is to combine different functions into **reusable** blocks. Order of applications is reversed compared to order of arguments so `compose(f, g, h)(x)` is `f(g(h(x)))` (same as *(f ∘ g)(x)* is  *f(g(x))*).

  `thread_*` and `pipe` are about using reusable blocks to create a single data flow.  Execution can be deferred only with lazy operations, but blocks are fixed. Order of application is the same as order of arguments so `pipe(x, f, g, h)` is `h(g(f(x)))`.
- `compose` vs `thread_*`.

  `compose` doesn't allow for additional arguments, while `thread_*` does. Without currying `compose` can be used only with unary functions.

  Compared to that `thread_` can be used with functions of higher arity, including commonly used higher order functions:

  ```
  thread_last(
      range(10),
      (map, lambda x: x + 1),
      (filter, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
  )
  ```

  To the same thing with `compose` you'd need currying:

  ```
  pipe(
      range(10), 
      lambda xs: map(lambda x: x + 1, xs), 
      lambda xs: filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, xs)
  )
  ```

  or

  ```
  from toolz import curried

  pipe(
      range(10), 
      curried.map(lambda x: x + 1), 
      curried.filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
  )
  ```
- `thread_first` vs. `thread_last`.

  `thread_first` puts piped argument at the first position for the function.

  `thread_last` puts piped argument at the last position for the function.

  For example

  ```
  >>> from operator import pow
  >>> thread_last(3, (pow, 2))   # pow(2, 3)
  8
  >>> thread_first(3, (pow, 2))  # pow(3, 2)
  9
  ```

In practice (ignoring some formalism) these functions are typically interchangeable, especially when combined with `functools.partial` / `toolz.curry` and some `lambda` expressions, but depending on the context, it is just more convenient to use one over another.

For example with built-in higher-order functions, like `map` or `functools.reduce`, `thread_last` is a natural choice. If you want to reuse a piece of code in multiple place, it is better to use `compose(h, g, f)` than adding function wrapper `def fgh(x) pipe(x, f, g, h)`. And so on.